# Why do ASP.NET MVC URLs need Index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Struggling to work out how to have the following

```
http://localhost/star/regulus
```

the only way it will work is to have a web address of

```
http://localhost/star/index/regulus
```

This is my routes

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute( "", "star/{sstar}", new { Controller = "star", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

and in the Controller, I set up the View as :-

```
return View("~/views/star.cshtml", oStar);
```

so you can see I'm not using `Index.cshtml`

Any ideas how I get the top web address, not the second one.

Comment: can you show all your route configs?

Comment: What does your RouteConfig.cs look like? You aren't giving the route a name.

Comment: Show the controller action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rearrange your routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "StarRoute",
    url: "star/{sstar}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Star", action = "Star", sstar = UrlParameter.Optional}
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

> The default controller should usually be the last route registered

Assuming controller

```
public class StarController :Controller {
    public ActionResult Star(string sstar){
        //...other code that uses sstar parameter
        return View();
    }
}
```

The view should be located at...

```
~/Views/Star/Star.cshtml
```

...for the following URIs to work:

```
http://localhost/star/regulus  
http://localhost/star?sstar=regulus
http://localhost/star/sirius  
http://localhost/star?sstar=sirius
```

Comment: Thanks Nkosi, it never occurred to me it was an arrangement problem.  However, instead of using ~/Views/Star/Regulus.cshtml, I'm using just ~/Views/Star.cshtml for every Star page, e.g. /star/sirius etc.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `every Star page`. Also what is the name of the controller where the action is associated with

Comment: I assumed `StarController` based on the route. would `sirius` be an action or parameter? MVC looks for the views based on convention

Comment: Am new to MVC so what I wanted to do was something that would be equivalent in the old style, http://localhost/star.aspx?sstar=regulus so star.cshtml would process them all.  That way, i don't have 3000 physical pages for 3000 stars.

Comment: Ok then that means that sirius is a parameter. Will update answer to match new information

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to the way I've done it, where the cshtml is in Views folder and not ~/Views/star/index.cshtml ?

Comment: by Convention the framework looks for views using something like `Views/{controllerName}/{actioName}`. So either create a folder for `Star` controller or you could put the view in the `Views/Shared` folder.